# How do I modify the Stroustrap C style in emacs

Tags: emacs

So I almost have the C style indentation that I want, but I am still new to emacs (over vim and other things) and can't seem to find what I want. I have this in my .emacs file and it mostly does what I want

```
(setq c-default-style "stroustrap" c-basic-offset 2)
```

I would like, however, to have my code indent like this instead:

```
void somefunc(
  int someInt,
  char someChar,
  float someFloat
) {
  // Code
}
```

Namely the ") {" line. I would like the closing parenthesis to line up with the v in void. It would also be nice to have my cases indented from the switch statements when they occur.

Answer (score 2):

You don't modify the preset styles.  You add you're own with `c-add-style` ([link](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Adding-Styles.html)).  For example styles, and information on creating your own, consult the [Emacs Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingC).